# PYTHON - What's the output of [1 : -1]

Tags: python

I wonder why is the output (2, 4) for the below code? I understand where is the 2 come from, but not the 4. Is that because [ : -1] is just an omission of [ : len(t)-2]?

```
t = (1, 2, 4, 3) 
print(t[1 : -1])

#output (2, 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = (1, 2, 4, 3) 
print(t[1 : -1])
```

`(t[1 : -1])` is 1 is start index with second element of list.
 `[1:-1]` is `-1` is last second element in list

Answer (score 2):

`print(t[1 : -1])` will print `t` from the second object `[1:]` until one before the last object `[:-1]`